# Several lines in a for loop

Tags: bash

I am currently working in a bash file that has to take from the folder we are in, two files at a time (that are identical but for a number), do something with them and then take other two and so on.

I've thought about doing it with a for loop:

```
 for file in $folder; do
     sort #this will leave them together
     if $file = "*1*"; then
        take the next one also
```

This is the best I can come with, but I am sure there has to be another way that I am not seeing.

Thanks

EDIT:

The files are like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L1_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-39_1.clean.fq.gz
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L1_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-39_2.clean.fq.gz
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L2_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-39_1.clean.fq.gz
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L2_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-39_2.clean.fq.gz
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L3_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-39_1.clean.fq.gz
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L3_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-39_2.clean.fq.gz
```

So the idea is do a bash script that will take 2 files at a time (the first 2 are identical but for the last 1/2 before clean, the next to are the same and so on), do something with those two, then take the next two.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking. Could you give some examples of these files, and describe in more detail what you want to do with them and in what way you're unable to do so? Some *actual* code would be nice, too.

Comment: Just edited with the files :)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
find "$folder" -name '*_1.clean.fq.gz' | while IFS= read -r line ; do
   common_prefix=`printf $line | sed -e 's/_1.clean.fq.gz$//'`
   file1=${common_prefix}_1.clean.fq.gz
   file2=${common_prefix}_2.clean.fq.gz
done
```

the `IFS= read -r line` is explained in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 (as suggested by @chepner)

You could add a couple of `test -f` to check if both `file1` and `file2` exist.

Comment: I have a question though. I have to remove also the firts set of "x"s. I am trying to do it with a second sed, but apparently won't work.

Comment: `printf "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_L1_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" | sed -e 's/^[^_]*//'` ?

Comment: That's the problem. The L1 has to stay.

Comment: Sure, my mistake. Should I do the printf after the first one? I tried to do something similar but it won't work

Answer (score -1):

Be careful, `for file in $folder` won't iterate over files in the given folder.

For example if `folder=abc`, the *for loop* will go for one iteration with `file` equal to `abc`, and then stop.

You have to provide the file list yourself in the way that suits you, for instance, in *bash*:

```
for file in $(find $folder -maxdepth 0 -type f); do...
```

Comment: [Don't use `for` to iterate over a list of files.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: This also doesn't address how to iterate over *pairs* of similar file names, as requested.